# How to make my custom linked list to use generics?

Tags: java, generics

I need to implement custom linked list using generics.

Here is what I've done

```
public class Node {
    Node next;
    Object data;

    public Node(Object data) {
        next = null;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Object getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Object dataValue) {
        data = dataValue;
    }

    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node nextValue) {
        next = nextValue;
    }
}


public class LinkedList {

    private Node head;
    private int size;

    public LinkedList() {
        head = new Node(null);
        size = 0;
    }

    public void add(Object data) {
        Node node = new Node(data);
        Node current = head;
        while (current.getNext() != null) {
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        current.setNext(node);
        size++;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public String toString() {
        Node current = head.getNext();
        String elements = "";
        while (current != null) {
            elements += "[" + current.getData().toString() + "]";
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        return elements;
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello there!");
        LinkedList list = new LinkedList();

        list.add("First node");
        list.add("Second node");
        list.add("Third node");
        list.add("Fourth node");
        list.add("Fifth node");

        System.out.println("Linked list contains " + list.getSize() + " nodes");
        System.out.println("Here they are: " + list);
    }
}
```

I have no idea or just didn't quite understand where i should use generics and how? Any ideas?

Comment: Why you don t use java LinkedList type ?

Comment: @GuillaumeS looks like homework

Comment: Luiggi, guessed wrong

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Is it that hard to believe that someone would try something like this just to learn?

Comment: @Heron if it's for self learning purposes, it's like a homework set to yourself by yourself, so still homework. By the way, I'm not against this (otherwise it would be downvoted and with a vote to close). I just don't support bad/misleading answers. Makoto's is a good example of how answers should be in this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *start* with the `Node` class; specifically, you make it such that it can contain any type of data.

You do that in this manner:

- Introduce a generic type parameter at the class level

  ```
  public class Node<T> { }
  ```
- Wherever you have `Object`, replace it with `T`.

  ```
  T data;
  ```
- Be sure to update references to other `Node` instances inside so that they're using the same generic argument.

  ```
  Node<T> next;
  ```

Now, you can address the issues in your `LinkedList` class in a similar way.

- Introduce a generic type parameter at the class level

  ```
  public class LinkedList<T> { }
  ```
- Change the argument of `add` from `Object` to `T`.

  ```
  public void add(T data) { }
  ```
- Add the generics to your `Node` instance(s) so that you're not using a raw type.

  ```
  private Node<T> head;
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You should consider going through the [Generics tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html). Specifically, read through the 'Generic Types' section.

Basically, your LinkedList and Node implementations need to be generic by simply declaring them as `LinkedList<T>` and `Node<T>`. Once you've changed the classes to be generic, you can then instantiate a parameterized LinkedList, such as:

```
LinkedList<String> stringList = new LinkedList<>();
```

The LinkedList is now type-safe and will only allow Strings to be stored.

Comment: Forgot to format the code - generic parameter wasn't showing up.

Comment: Okay.  ***Much*** better.  Had me worried there for a moment.